# Existence of non-zero $G$-invariant global section of a vector bundle

Tags: algebraic-geometry, group-actions, vector-bundles

Let $f:Y\to X$ be a Galois, etale map between smooth quasi-projective varieties with (finite) Galois group $G$. Let $\mathcal{E}$ be a vector bundle on $X$ and let $\mathcal{F}=f^*\mathcal{E}$ on $Y$. Then one can make the identification $H^0(X,\mathcal{E})=H^0(Y,\mathcal{F})^G$.
My question is the following: If we know that $H^0(Y,\mathcal{F})\neq0$, then when can we say that $H^0(X,\mathcal{F})^G=H^0(X,\mathcal{E})\neq0$? I know that this is not true in general: one counterexample I was told is: X an elliptic curve with $\mathcal{E}$ a torsion line bundle on $X$, and $Y$ a cover of $X$ that trivializes $\mathcal{E}$. Then $f^*\mathcal{E}$ has global sections but $\mathcal{E}$ doesn't.
However, are there some extra assumptions that would guarantee descent of non-zero global sections? I specifically care about the case $\mathcal{E}=\textrm{Sym}^i\Omega^1_X$ but a more general treatment would be great.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that $X$ is a scheme over a field of characteristic prime to the order of $G$.

Let $R_0,R_1,\dots,R_k$ be all irreducible representations of $G$, and assume that $R_0$ is the trivial representation. Clearly, the sheaf $f_\ast\mathcal{O}_{Y}$ has the structure of a representation of $G$ (which is the regular representation pointwise), hence there is a direct sum decomposition
$$
f_\ast\mathcal{O}_{Y} \cong \bigoplus_{i=0}^k R_i \otimes \mathcal{V}_i,
$$
where $\mathcal{V}_i$ is a vector bundle on $X$ of rank equal to $\dim(R_i)$
(with $\mathcal{V}_0 = \mathcal{O}_X$). Consequently,
$$
f_\ast\mathcal{F} \cong
f_\ast f^\ast\mathcal{E} \cong
\mathcal{E} \otimes f_\ast\mathcal{O}_{Y} \cong
\bigoplus_{i=0}^k R_i \otimes (\mathcal{E} \otimes \mathcal{V}_i),
$$
and therefore
$$
H^0(Y,\mathcal{F}) = 
\bigoplus_{i=0}^k R_i \otimes H^0(X, \mathcal{E} \otimes \mathcal{V}_i).
$$
This shows that a global section of $\mathcal{F}$ can come from a global section of either of the vector bundles $\mathcal{E} \otimes \mathcal{V}_i$,
so if you want to ensure that it comes from the summand with $i = 0$, it is enough to check that the other summands have no global sections.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So the vector bundles $\mathcal{V}_i$ correspond to irreducible components of the regular representation of $G$? Also, I know that averaging over the elements of $G$ gives an invariant section, but a priori this could be zero. Are there criteria for when such an average of a non-zero section is again non-zero?